# Seaborn lineplot without lines between points

Tags: python, seaborn

How can I use the `lineplot` plotting function in seaborn to create a plot with no lines connecting between the points. I know the function is called lineplot, but it has the useful feature of merging all datapoints with the same x value and plotting a single mean and confidence interval.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.lineplot(x='size', y='total_bill', data=tips, marker='o', err_style='bars')
```

[image: lineplot]

How do I plot without the line? I'm not sure of a better way to phrase my question. How can I plot points only? Lineless lineplot?

I know that seaborn has a `pointplot` function, but that is for categorical data. In some cases, my x-values are continuous values, so `pointplot` would not work.

I realize one could get into the matplotlib figure artists and delete the line, but that gets more complicated as the amount of stuff on the plot increases. I was wondering if there are some sort of arguments that can be passed to the `lineplot` function.

Comment: What about [scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) ? i.e. `sns.scatterplot(...)`

Comment: The arguments that would enable aggregating points with the same x-values are currently nonfunctional: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Comment: There's a bit of confusion about what you want. If you're looking to not have the lines between the dots themselves, you wouldn't have a line, so lineplot would not work. If that the case you would want to something like sort the data into bins, plot the mean or average along with standard dev or CI.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't have a line, but that's what I want. The convenience of seaborn is that it automatically calculates a confidence interval by bootstrap sampling or uses standard deviation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get error bars without the connecting lines, you can set the [`linestyle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) parameter to `''`:

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.lineplot(x='size', y='total_bill', data=tips, marker='o', linestyle='', err_style='bars')
```

[image: no line]

Other types of linestyle could also be interesting, for example "a loosely dotted line": `sns.lineplot(..., linestyle=(0, (1, 10)))`

[image: loosely dotted]

Comment: Thanks. I think I had tried linestyle=None or linestyle='none' which did not work

Comment: One more note, seaborn 0.11+ is needed. I had 0.10.1 which did not work.

Comment: For anyone looking to just have the above but without the bars just use: ```linestyle='',marker='o'```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting join=False.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me only join = True works.

```
sns.pointplot(data=df, x = "x_attribute", y = "y_attribute", ci= 95, join=False)
```